# Print Webkit report gives Error

Tags: python, webkit, report, odoo, openerp-7

I'm using 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04. When i'm installed `wkhtmltopdf` package. When I print web kit report  it's show following error.

`Wkhtmltopdf` library path is not set

Please install executable on your system (sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf) or download it from here: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list and set the path in the `ir.config_parameter` with the `webkit_path` `key.Minimal` version is `0.9.9`

Please Help me to configure the webkit package

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, i solved mine using this one

http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2

everything else is same as @Adrian Merrall explained.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to just head to http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ and grab the 64 bit download rather than use the deb package (although that should work too).

Unpack it somewhere and ensure the same user running OpenERP has execute rights on it.

Test from bash with wkhtmltopdf --version

In OpenERP - Settings -> Parameters -> System Parameters -> webkit_path

Set to the full path, e.g.
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

and you should be in business

Comment: Thanks for your kind replay. I follow your step but it's give new this error "The switch --header-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.
The switch --footer-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored."